# Correct syntax for including boolean expressions in XPath; specifically not & and

Tags: xpath, boolean

In order to find `<li>` elements that contain the text "memory" but not the text "Graphics", I have tried a dozen variation of:

```
//li[contains(text(), "memory")] and li[not contains(text(), "Graphics")]
//li[contains(text(), "memory")] and [not contains(text(), "Graphics")]
//li[contains(text(), "memory") and not contains(text(), "Graphics")]
etc etc
```

While I've found posts on Stackoverflow that point to the use of individual boolean operators like `not`, I can find nothing that explains how to combine them to filter text like this. What's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[not()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-not) is a *function* in XPath, not an operator. You have to write:

```
//li[contains(text(), "memory") and not(contains(text(), "Graphics"))]
```